# how to replace text between 2 slashes with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a src attribute that I only want to replace whatever dimensions happen to be between `b1/` and `/imglibrary`:
`b1/200x300/imglibrary`

```
<img class="Img" src="b1/200x300/imglibrary" alt=""/>
var $image = $('.Img').attr('src');
var editedImage = $image.replace(/b1\/.*?\/imglibrary/,"b1/800x600/imglibrary");
console.log(editedImage);
```

but the output is:
`/imglibrary/b1/800x600/imglibrary/`

I can't simply find and replace the text 200x300 because that text will change based on the image. Can anyone please shed some light on where I am going wrong?

Comment: The feature you are interested in is capturing groupes. [See this documentation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming, that you want to replace resolution value, which pattern looks like `numberxnumber`, use following `RegExp`:

```js
var $image = $('.Img').attr('src');
var editedImage = $image.replace(/(?!\/)\d+x\d+(?=\/)/, "800x600");
console.log(editedImage);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="Img" src="b1/200x300/imglibrary" alt=""/>
```